# Returning Null from Array.map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, remix

I am trying to get data from a JS object by using array.map() function. However, the output I am getting is null. I am not able to understand the problem here.

This is the object

```
export const Course = [
  {
    course_id: "001-TTE-ADIT",
    course_description:"XXXX",
    course_title: "XXXX",
    course_faculty: "XXXX",
    course_duration: "XXXX",
    course_lectures_count: "XXXX",
    course_fees: XXXX,
    course_section: [
      {
        section_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S01",
        section_name: "XXXX",
        section_description:
          "TXXXX.",
        section_duration: 3,
        section_lecture_count: 3,
        section_lectures: [
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S01-LE01",
            lecture_name: "XXXX",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX.",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 1,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S01-LE02",
            lecture_name: "XXXX",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX.",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 0.5,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        section_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S02",
        section_name: "XXXX",
        section_description:
          "XXXX",
        section_duration: 5,
        section_lecture_count: 5,
        section_lectures: [
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE03",
            lecture_name: "XXXX",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 1,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE04",
            lecture_name: "XXXX",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 1,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE05",
            lecture_name: "XXXX",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 1,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

And this is the function for getting data from object

```
import { Course } from "../../Data/Courses";

export const getListLectures = async () => {
  let lecture_list = [];

  lecture_list = Course.map((course) => {
    course.course_section?.map((section) => {
      section.section_lectures?.map((lecture) => {
        lecture_list.push(lecture?.lecture_name);
      });
    });
  });

  return lecture_list;
};
```

The expected outcome from this function was list of lectures which lie within each section for the given course.

Comment: You are using the Array.map() wrong!! 
If you want to push in the different array then use forEach loop
You are assigning `lecture_list` a new array and pushing also.

Comment: You seem to have a severe misunderstanding what `Array.map` does and how it works. The callbacks of your `map` do not return anything, thus your `lecture_list` will be an array with `undefined` elements. And don't manipulate the array you are assigning your result to.

Comment: What if I use a temporary array for array.push() and then assign the temporary array to lecture_list? Like this:  `export const getListLectures = async () => {
  let lecture_list = [];
  let lecture_tempo_list = [];
  lecture_list = Course.map((course) => {
    course.course_section?.map((section) => {
      section.section_lectures?.map((lecture) => {
        return lecture_tempo_list.push(lecture?.lecture_name);
      });
    });
  });

  return lecture_list;
};`

Comment: Are you just expecting a flat array of _all_ lecture names, or are you expecting a set of names corresponding to the section they're in (which would most likely be an object with the section names as keys, and their lecture names as an array as the value)?

Comment: Flat array with lectures names

Comment: Also, somewhere I read that `array.foreach()` is 70% slower than `array.map()` and hence I thought to use `array.map()` instead of `array.foreach()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mix of `map` and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) - making sure you return each mapped array each time.

For the purposes of this example:

1. I've changed `Course` to `courses` to better match the data description
2. I had to change the value of `course_fees` to zero
3. I changed the names of the lectures so you can better understand the output.

```js
const courses=[{course_id:"001-TTE-ADIT",course_description:"XXXX",course_title:"XXXX",course_faculty:"XXXX",course_duration:"XXXX",course_lectures_count:"XXXX",course_fees:0,course_section:[{section_id:"001-TTE-ADIT-S01",section_name:"XXXX",section_description:"TXXXX.",section_duration:3,section_lecture_count:3,section_lectures:[{lecture_id:"001-TTE-ADIT-S01-LE01",lecture_name:"1111",lecture_description:"XXXX.",lecture_faculty:"XXXX",lecture_duration:1,lecture_link:"#",lecture_notes:[{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"}]},{lecture_id:"001-TTE-ADIT-S01-LE02",lecture_name:"2222",lecture_description:"XXXX.",lecture_faculty:"XXXX",lecture_duration:.5,lecture_link:"#",lecture_notes:[{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"}]}]},{section_id:"001-TTE-ADIT-S02",section_name:"XXXX",section_description:"XXXX",section_duration:5,section_lecture_count:5,section_lectures:[{lecture_id:"001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE03",lecture_name:"3333",lecture_description:"XXXX",lecture_faculty:"XXXX",lecture_duration:1,lecture_link:"#",lecture_notes:[{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"}]},{lecture_id:"001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE04",lecture_name:"4444",lecture_description:"XXXX",lecture_faculty:"XXXX",lecture_duration:1,lecture_link:"#",lecture_notes:[{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"}]},{lecture_id:"001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE05",lecture_name:"5555",lecture_description:"XXXX",lecture_faculty:"XXXX",lecture_duration:1,lecture_link:"#",lecture_notes:[{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"},{note_title:"XXXX",note_link:"#"}]}]}]}];

const lectureNames = courses.flatMap(course => {
  return course.course_section.flatMap(section => {
    return section.section_lectures.map(lecture => {
      return lecture.lecture_name;
    });
  });
});

console.log(lectureNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not returning returning from `Course.map()`. Thats why it is returning undefined,
The other problem is that you are assigning `Array.map`'s result to `lecture_list` and also pushing the results in the same array

If you are not returning from `Array.map`, better to use `Array.forEach` or other loops

```js
const Course = [
  {
    course_id: "001-TTE-ADIT",
    course_description:"XXXX",
    course_title: "XXXX",
    course_faculty: "XXXX",
    course_duration: "XXXX",
    course_lectures_count: "XXXX",
    course_fees: "XXXX",
    course_section: [
      {
        section_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S01",
        section_name: "XXXX",
        section_description:
          "TXXXX.",
        section_duration: 3,
        section_lecture_count: 3,
        section_lectures: [
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S01-LE01",
            lecture_name: "lec_1",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX.",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 1,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S01-LE02",
            lecture_name: "lec_2",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX.",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 0.5,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        section_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S02",
        section_name: "XXXX",
        section_description:
          "XXXX",
        section_duration: 5,
        section_lecture_count: 5,
        section_lectures: [
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE03",
            lecture_name: "lec_3",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 1,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE04",
            lecture_name: "lec_4",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 1,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            lecture_id: "001-TTE-ADIT-S00-LE05",
            lecture_name: "lec_5",
            lecture_description:
              "XXXX",
            lecture_faculty: "XXXX",
            lecture_duration: 1,
            lecture_link: "#",
            lecture_notes: [
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
              {
                note_title: "XXXX",
                note_link: "#",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];


const getListLectures = () => {
  let lecture_list = [];

  Course.forEach((course) => {
    course.course_section?.forEach((section) => {
      section.section_lectures?.forEach((lecture) => {
        lecture_list.push(lecture?.lecture_name);
      });
    });
  });
  return lecture_list;
};

console.log(getListLectures())
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably just using some nested loops. Ie iterate over all courses, and for each course iterate over all sections and for each section iterate over all lectures and push the name of the lecture in the resulting array.

```
let lectures = [];
for (let c of Course) {
  for (let cs of c.course_section) {
    for (let l of cs.section_lectures) {
      lectures.push(l.lecture_name);
    }
  }
}
```

But you could also use a combination of `flatMap` and `map`. Ie first use two levels of flatMap to get a flat list of lectures and then map each of the lectures to its name for the result array.

```
let lectures = Course
    .flatMap(c =>  c.course_section.flatMap(cs => cs.section_lectures))
    .map(l => l.lecture_name)
```