# loader function not returning the data in remix.run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix, remix.run

I am trying to get the data in `loader()` function and then passing that data into `useLoaderData` hook. However, what I am getting is null. Usually the function `getListLectures` should return a list which is happening in  `console.log(getListLectures()` on line 6.

```
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { getListLectures } from "../Shared/getStoredNotes";

export default function LectureList() {
let lectures = useLoaderData();
//   console.log(getListLectures());
console.log("this is lecture " + lectures);
return (
<main>
  {lectures ? (
    <ul>
      {lectures.map((eachLecture) => (
        <li key={lectures.indexOf(eachLecture)}>{eachLecture}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  ) : (
    <p>No Data Found</p>
  )}
</main>
);
}

export const loader = async () => {
let lectures = await getListLectures();
console.log(lectures);
return lectures;
};
```

For the reference purpose here is the code for `getListLectures`

```
import { Course } from "../../Data/Courses";

export const getListLectures = async () => {
  let lecture_list = [];
  Course.forEach((course) => {
    course.course_section?.forEach((section) => {
      section.section_lectures?.forEach((lecture) => {
        lecture_list.push(lecture?.lecture_name);
      });
    });
  });
  return lecture_list;
};
```

The expected output should be a list which should be iterated using `map` function

The part where I took help from community with respect to `getListLecture()` [Returning Null from Array.map() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472621/returning-null-from-array-map-function?noredirect=1#comment134839683_76472621)

Comment: The part where I took help from the community for `getListLectures` is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472621/returning-null-from-array-map-function?noredirect=1#comment134839683_76472621

Comment: The code should work. Here's a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-srpuv4?file=app%2Froutes%2Flectures.tsx

Comment: Actually this `loader` function and `LectureList()` is a JSX component that is then used in the route. So currently it is not in the route folder. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Yes. Loaders and actions must be exported from a route module. Remix does not support component-level loaders... yet.

You can re-export your loader and component from your route if you want to keep them separate.

I do have a POC for component-level loaders. https://github.com/kiliman/remix-component-data

Comment: @Kiliman Thank you for the help. Your solution worked. I was trying to fit `loader` in the component instead of the route.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code looks fine. One thing I can think of that loader won't be considered when you are not declaring in a route component. By nature, Remix will only consider loader exported from route.

Definition from documentation:
`Each route can define a "loader" function that provides data to the route when rendering.`

[Reference](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/loader)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
export const loader = async () => {
let lectures = await getListLectures();
console.log(lectures);
return lectures;
};
```

use

```
export const loader = async () => {
let lectures = await getListLectures();
console.log(lectures);
return json(lectures);
};
```

as using JSON an api call is made. That allows the frontend to get the updated data. this you can confirm by console.logging the json(lectures).