# Not able to pass any data from loader to useLoaderData in remix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I am trying to set up `loader` function where in the function should return a list of names, and then such names I want to capture in `useLoaderData()` function. However, I feel the `loader()` is not getting triggered as I am also not getting `console.log(listOfNames)` output in my console. The outcome I am getting is `null`

Below is the code of my JSX Component. This Component is then imported into a route.

```
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { getDataFromReqRes, getListLectures } from "../Shared/getStoredNotes";

export default function LectureList() {
  let nameList = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <main>
      {nameList.length ? (
        <ul>
          {nameList.map((nameOfPerson) => (
            <li key={nameList.indexOf(nameOfPerson)}>{nameOfPerson}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <p>No Data Found</p>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}

export const loader = async () => {
  let listOfNames = await getDataFromReqRes();
  console.log(listOfNames);
  return listOfNames;
};
```

This is function is in another file which is imported in above JSX Component

```
export const getDataFromReqRes = async () => {
  let res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
  let rawData = JSON.stringify(res);
  let data = rawData.data;
  let listOfNames;
  data.forEach((person) => listOfNames.push(person.first_name));
  return listOfNames;
};
```

The expected outcome should be a list of names from this open API. This is a remix.run app. The outcome I am getting is `null`.

This is full error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at LectureList (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\app\components\AcademyComponents\lecture-list.jsx:15:17)
    at renderWithHooks (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:5724:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:5797:15)
    at renderElement (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:6012:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:6170:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:6142:14)
    at renderNode (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:6325:12)
    at renderChildrenArray (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:6277:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:6207:7)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\the-taxeco-academy-v2\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:6142:14)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `listOfNames` is defined or initialized to any value. Are there any errors about `.push` not being a function? Does `rawData` have the value you expect? Normally you need to also `await res.json()` the fetched response object. The code you have here is stringifying `res` for some reason, so `rawData.data` will also be undefined.

Comment: @DrewReese I am not able to check that because `console.log()` function in `loader()` or in `getDataFromReqRes()` is not working. I am not able to see any output in my console even when I have `console.log()` statement within the function.

Comment: @DrewReese I was facing a similar issue when I was trying to fetch data from a local file. Here is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474735/loader-function-not-returning-the-data-in-remix-run?noredirect=1#comment134843881_76474735

Comment: As I stated in my other answer, loaders and actions must be exported from a route module, not a component. Remix will call your loader automatically when the route matches. If you must call from a component, then look into useFetcher and resource routes.

Comment: @Kiliman Thank you for the help. Your solution worked. I was trying to fit `loader` in the component instead of the route.